# I have searched for FOSUserBundle private profile, to no avail

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

So I have tried to make a symfony project that contains private profiles, and I use FriendsOfSymfony, but if I create a two users, each one can see the others uploaded file. I tried to search on multiple websites and failed to find something that worked for me.
example:
[Adding extended profile entity to FOS UserBundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14968969/adding-extended-profile-entity-to-fos-userbundle)

I want to create private profiles for each user to upload files, no one except them should be able to see them(only the admin and the specific user).

Comment: Easiest way would be to extend the FOSUser ProfileController (overwriting the showAction) and apply some logic to the showAction to deny other users from viewing the profile.

Answer (score 1):

Question is very broad.

**You need to introduce authentication to your application.**

And add `user id` or `user relation` to your uploaded files. Then in controller where you list/show that files (`/profile/my-uploads`) - load only files which belongs to this specific (logged in) user.

For admin access - best will be creating special back-office or implement [User Impersonation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/impersonating_user.html).

Read more about it in Symfony documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authentication.html

Comment: I have authentication on the application, i can make users that require username and password to log in, but anyone that has an account can see what any user uploaded

Answer (score 1):

Provided you have extended

> Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller

or FOSUserBundle Controller you could try doing something like this:

```
public function publicProfileAction($handleOrHash = '')
{
    if ($handleOrHash == '') {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException("Unable to find this user");
    }

    $user = $this->getUserService()->getUserByHandleOrHash($handleOrHash);

    if (!$user) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException("Unable to find this user");
    }

    if ($user != $this->getUser()) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException("You cannot see this user profile");
    }

    return $this->render('MyUserBundle:Default:public-profile.html.twig',
        array('user' => $user)
    );
}
```

Where getUserService() will return an object which has access to the userRepository with a method called getUserByHandleOrHash() which uses the repository to make the doctrine query.

Comment: should I put it in user.php? I am not that experienced with symfony, I need some more guidance if you want to give

Comment: Is user.php your user entity?  This code above would go inside a controller.  You might be best reading over:  

https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_controllers.html
It is hard for me to guide you exactly without seeing your code.

Comment: Thanks for the link, and yes user.php is the user entity. I am sorry for the late answer, will read the doc and maybe will fix the problem, thank you for the interest you took in my question and the answers you have given me so far !

Comment: I added the code to the user.php and extended the controller, yet I still log on two different computers and see the same content on both. Any ideas? I have read the fosuserbundle override controllers and modified it.